# Swift - Grouped Style tableview design

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, uistoryboard

I am trying to design the grouped style tableview in Xcode 6.3. I don't get rectangle box covering the table like the second image i have attached below. Can you please tell how to build a screen like the second one?

[image]

[image]

Comment: The second image is iOS6 style not iOS7

Comment: so I can't build like second one in Xcode 6.3.1 with iOS 8.3?

Comment: You will had to create a custom table if you want your app to look like that

Comment: You can create a custom cell or tableView

Comment: @IcaroNZ/Banning, appreciate if you provide some example for this. I am new to iOS development.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a example for iOS7 here:

https://github.com/yesidi/YipPrettyTableViewCell

---

**EDIT:** I made a simple cell using Swift.
[image]

```
// GroupedTableViewCell.swift
import UIKit

let RADIUS: CGFloat = 5
let InsetX: CGFloat = 20

enum CellPosition : Int {

    case Top
    case Mid
    case Bottom
    case TopAndBottom
}


class GroupedTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    var cellPosition: CellPosition?

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {

        if self.cellPosition != nil {
            self.drawMask()
        } else {
            self.layer.mask = nil
            super.drawRect(rect)
        }
    }

    // MARK: - Private methods

    func drawMask() {
        let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        maskLayer.frame = CGRectInset(self.bounds, InsetX, 0)

        var path = CGPathCreateMutable()

        let minX = CGRectGetMinX(maskLayer.bounds)
        let midX = CGRectGetMidX(maskLayer.bounds)
        let maxX = CGRectGetMaxX(maskLayer.bounds)
        let minY = CGRectGetMinY(maskLayer.bounds)
        let midY = CGRectGetMidY(maskLayer.bounds)
        let maxY = CGRectGetMaxY(maskLayer.bounds)

        if let cellPosition = self.cellPosition {
            switch cellPosition {
            case .Top:
                CGPathMoveToPoint(path, nil, minX, maxY)
                CGPathAddArcToPoint(path, nil, minX, minY, midX, minY, RADIUS)
                CGPathAddArcToPoint(path, nil, maxX, minY, maxX, maxY, RADIUS)
                CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, maxX, maxY)
                CGPathCloseSubpath(path)
            case .Mid:
                CGPathAddRect(path, nil, maskLayer.bounds)
            case .Bottom:
                CGPathMoveToPoint(path, nil, minX, minY)
                CGPathAddArcToPoint(path, nil, minX, maxY, midX, maxY, RADIUS)
                CGPathAddArcToPoint(path, nil, maxX, maxY, maxX, minY, RADIUS)
                CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, maxX, minY)
                CGPathCloseSubpath(path)
            case .TopAndBottom:
                CGPathMoveToPoint(path, nil, minX, midY)
                CGPathAddArcToPoint(path, nil, minX, maxY, midX, maxY, RADIUS)
                CGPathAddArcToPoint(path, nil, maxX, maxY, maxX, midY, RADIUS)
                CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, maxX, midY)
                CGPathAddArcToPoint(path, nil, maxX, minY, midX, minY, RADIUS)
                CGPathAddArcToPoint(path, nil, minX, minY, minX, midY, RADIUS)
                CGPathCloseSubpath(path)
            }
        }

        maskLayer.path = path
        maskLayer.fillColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor
        maskLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
        self.layer.mask = maskLayer

    }
}
```

Now you can set the cell's position:

```
// TableViewController.swift
// MARK: - Table view data source
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    assert(cell.isKindOfClass(GroupedTableViewCell.self), "")

    let groupedCell = cell as! GroupedTableViewCell

    let numberOfRows = tableView.numberOfRowsInSection(indexPath.section) - 1

    groupedCell.cellPosition = (indexPath.row == numberOfRows && indexPath.row == 0) ? .TopAndBottom : ((indexPath.row == 0) ? .Top : (indexPath.row == numberOfRows ? .Bottom : .Mid))
}
```

I hope that helps you!

Comment: Thanks Banning. any example for swift?